# Shifting from EXPO ..Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key

Tags: android, flutter, expo

My old android app was deployed by expo and new one is by flutter.. How I can get the old keystore file. 
It was managed by expo and now I cant download it.

When I try 'expo fetch:android:keystore'
I get 
'There is no valid Keystore defined for this app'